# Angular 8 and Material Missing

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-material-8

I am trying to create a template with a paginated table and am using the example from https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#pagination which has a link to a stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/angular/bymxnvovkvk

When I download the code, run npm install and then ng serve I see a page that looks simialar, but is missing some Material design and looks very flat. When I try to add other material items like a Sidenav, I get errors stating "can not find module “@angular/material”. I verified that it is included, but why would it not work on my machine if its working on stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had a problem with Angular material not working properly. I installed it through `npm`, but it seems that the better solution is to use,

`ng add @angular/material`.

This should work fine and make angular material work properly.
You also might want to uninstall `@angular/material` first, using:

`npm uninstall @angular/material`

Hope it helps!

**PS** Say *no* to the `HammerJS` option when it is installing.

**Suggested reading:** https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: Your answer did help. I did that and was able to get it to style correctly after adding the theme to the angular.json file as menitoned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56016261/1486716